How to set referrerpolicy on inline style attribute (e.g. background-image)
As the title suggests I'm struggling to add referrerpolicy on resources loaded via inline style attribute.
I know I can set the following:
<img src="https://myseconddomain.com/image.png" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">

And the request will be executed without Referer HTTP header.
However, I am trying to achieve this:
<div style="background-image:url('https://myseconddomain.com/image.png')"></div>

According to the spec, the <div> element is not allowed to have referrerpolicy attribute. Also from the spec, we see that there is a method to add the policy to inline style attributes:


External CSS stylesheets use the default policy (strict-origin-when-cross-origin), unless it's overwritten by a Referrer-Policy HTTP header on the CSS stylesheet's response.
For  elements or style attributes, the owner document's referrer policy is used.


Which means that I should be able to use the referrer meta header on the whole document to control this. This is not preferable, as I don't want to override the policy on the whole page, but it also doesn't seem to work. In the following example requests to myseconddomain.com still contain Referer HTTP header:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-image:url('https://myseconddomain.com/image.png')"></div>
</body>
</html>

I am testing with Google Chrome Stable 124.0.6367.207.
Am I doing something wrong or is this actually broken?

Are you perhaps providing a referrer policy via HTTP response header already? Those take precedence over meta tags.

What happens when you click a normal link in that document - does it send a referrer then, or is your meta tag setting applied?
